# Is a virtual method whose only purpose is to modify a private variable sensible design?

Tags: c#, inheritance

oo design basics here...

Edit:
To clarify after first answer - I'm not asking how to fix this but whether on the face of it the design seems screwy.  I don't want to point out the original code for social considerations.

I'm working with some code that has a virtual method which does nothing but modify a private member variable of the class.  I'd like to just change the details of that modification.  That's the only behavior I want to change, but I can't reference the private member, so I can't just override the method.  On the face of it, is that design by the original author wrong/odd, or is this not enough information to say?

```
public class X
{
    private List<string> InterestingThings = new List<string>();

    public virtual void MethodIWantToOverride(string rawData)
    {

         string fixedData = ... 
         // do some fancy stuff to clean up data that I want to come thru 'dirty'
         InterestingThings.Add(fixedData);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the purpose of the code is to enforce some invariant upon items which get added to the list, requiring that all attempts to add items to the list go through a virtual method would be a way to achieve that.  Exposing the list field as `protected` would allow derived classes to violate the base-class invariant.  If that's what you're trying to do, and if you will be upholding all portions of the invariant that code actually relies upon, you might make the list field `protected`, but I would suggest that you at least consider adding another protected, possible virtual, base-class method to mutate it in a way that upholds a weaker invariant.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not asking though how to fix it, I just changed my copy to be what I wanted.  I asked the question because it seemed weird to me to have a virtual method exists solely to modify a private variable, the purpose of modifying a private member variable.  I was looking for an answer like "Yeah, that looks crazy" or "You do that when there are a group of methods all using the same private variable, that you would override in concert".

Comment: @LevinMagruder: It sounded like you were asking whether the original design was screwy, or if there was a reason for it.  I offered up a reason: allowing derived classes a means of affecting the items get stored, but not in such fashion as to violate the base-class invariant.

Comment: sorry I wasn't following, so thanks for the suggestion. Yes the original author's point is to make sure that everything in the list gets is stripped of control/space characters and is not null/empty, so I think that's what you're calling "enforcing an invariant".  What I fail to see is why the method should be virtual.  There are a few other members that all use the same private variable, so they'd all have to be overriden at the same time.  I guess there's no syntactic way to express "these three methods go together", and there was no comment.

Comment: @LevinMagruder: Whether or not they should all be virtual depends upon what they are doing.  For example, if there were two methods, one of which set the variable and the other of which read it, the code might deliberately make the setter virtual and the getter not, so as to allow derived classes to enforce additional invariants, but not violate any invariants of the base class.  If the getter were virtual, it could return a value which didn't comply with the requirements enforced by the base class.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that last comment up. Whatever the intentions of the author and merits of his code, your comment got me to rethink & improve what I was doing.

Comment: @LevinMagruder: My pleasure.  I think `protected` and `private` are not as well understood as they might be; I also wish, btw, there was a common convention for making a parent's `protected` member unavailable to derived classes (or even marking a protected member so that it would only be available to sub-derived classes if the immediate derived class explicitly makes it available).  Such behavior would be appropriate for things like `MemberwiseClone()`, which is generally left available even on classes where it cannot be used without violating class invariants.

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be defined as a `protected` variable instead of `private` for a `virtual` method to modify it.

I would recommend this change and leaving the method as `virtual`, because that guaruntees that you will not break anything outside of this class. The original dev may have intended on overriding the virtual method in a derived class. If you have no way of knowing or testing that this is the case, then leave the method as `virtual` and change the `private` member to `protected`.

[More reading on virtual methods here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: What I was wondering is, given just the information above, does it make sense to suggest to the author of the code that they make the member protected (I can do it to my own copy).  Or can you imagine there are cases where that might be sensible design?

Comment: @BumbleB2na, what does, "I would recommend this change and leaving the method as `virtual`" mean?  Are you recommending a change?  Or recommending leaving the method alone.  I'm not following.

Comment: Leave the virtual keyword there because the original developer may have intended on overriding the virtual method in a derived class. The change he needs to make is to change the private member to protected, because that is what the original dev should have already done.

Comment: @BumbleB2na, I disagree that making a private field protected is the way to go.  Once you embark down that path, it makes more sense to surface a property.

Comment: @Kirk Woll - I agree with you. If I was confident that nothing else is overriding the virtual method then I would surface the property, too. It would be less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the property private ensures that only the containing class can see it. Setting it to protected will allow derived classes to see and use it as well. If you need a derived class to override a method that requires access to this property, as you do above, you must make the property and the method (at the least) protected.